# Solr 6.3 splits rawquerystring into two-letter pairs

Tags: solr

My Solr 6.3.0 parses rawquerystring into windowed 2-letter pairs.

For example, when I search for "source", Solr parses it into ["so", "ou", "ur", "rc", "ce"].

```
  "debug":{
    "rawquerystring":"source",
    "querystring":"source",
    "parsedquery":"+text_all:so +text_all:ou +text_all:ur +text_all:rc +text_all:ce",
    "parsedquery_toString":"+text_all:so +text_all:ou +text_all:ur +text_all:rc +text_all:ce"
```

---

text_all is defined as

```
<field indexed="true" multiValued="true" name="text_all" omitNorms="false" omitPositions="false" omitTermFreqAndPositions="false" stored="false" termVectors="false" type="text_general" />
```

---

And text_general is defined as

```
   <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
         <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="2" />
         <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
         <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
         <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
         <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="2" />
         <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
         <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
         <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
   </fieldType>
```

Any suggstions?

Thank you!

Lei

Answer (score 0):

It's because of NGramTokenizerFactory